# Distance between 2 latlon points

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, distance

I want to work out the distance between 2 latlon points.
The simple distance formula http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm is not correct because we are dealing with 2 different measures (lat and lon).

Is there a standard solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Haversine formula`.

see this link http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

try this,
This uses the ‘haversine’ formula to calculate great-circle distances between the two points – that is, the shortest distance over the earth’s surface – giving an ‘as-the-crow-flies’ distance between the points (ignoring any hills!).

Haversine formula:

```
R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
```

Δlat = lat2− lat1
Δlong = long2− long1
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c

or go with the link,http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript haversine function alongside the torad() helper function, which I use for my map app

```
function calculateHaversineDistance(lat1x, lon1, lat2x, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLat = toRad(lat2x-lat1x);
    var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
    var lat1 = toRad(lat1x);
    var lat2 = toRad(lat2x);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    return R * c;
 }
function toRad(x) {
    return x * Math.PI / 180;
 }
```

Hope this helps.